# Interface with Method body vs Abstract class

Tags: c#, interface

Nowadays, C# is supporting method body, Static variable declaration and assign value to it in an interface, then what is the use of abstract class?

Comment: The ability to use non-static private implementation methods, for starters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570814/when-to-use-abstract-classes

Comment: Now a days Interface is also supporting Body of function so,Why still abstract class Is there ?