# PHP unable to display a form inside a table

Tags: php, html

I must be missing something incredibly simple, but I can't see it. I have a function that generates a simple form that should be displayed several times within a table. Whenever I try to call the function with in a table cell, the form is displayed **above** the table for some reason.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

**Php function that generates a form to be displayed multiple times**

```
private function addTaskForm()
{
   // display add task form
   echo "<form method='post' action='#'>
           <select name='task'>
             <option value='1'>Clean</option>
             <option value='1'>Shop</option>
           </select>
           <input type='submit' name='btnSubmit'>
         </form>";
}
```

**Table**

```
echo "<table>
        <tr>
          <td>".addTaskForm()."</td> 
          <td>".addTaskForm()."</td>
          <td>".addTaskForm()."</td> 
          <td>".addTaskForm()."</td>
        </tr>
      </table>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to echo on function just return string and i am sure you know about public/private/protected  function

[**codepad**](http://codepad.org/1lw6vDbX)

---

**Good Read**

1. [PHP: Public, Private, Protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected)
2. [For comprehensive information : Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)