# Entities have "public" variables

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm learning Symfony2 now and in every tutorial I read, there are `protected` variables, like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
 */
protected $price;

/**
  * @ORM\Column(type="text")
  */
protected $description;
```

What I got from the command line generator is:

```
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="game", type="integer")
 */
private $game;
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: You should use private variables. More is not needed. And if the Symfony2 generator do it i think its correct. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Protected is not public !

`private scope` when you want your variable to be visible in its own class only.

`protected scope` when you want to make your variable visible in all classes that **extend** current class including the parent class.

There isn't a big difference in this exemple. The code from the SF documentation is more open to inheritance, that's all. Both are working.

(source: [What is the difference between public, private, and protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected))