# private methods and variables in PHP usage

Tags: php, oop

I have been thinking about the usage of `private` variables and methods in php.

I am not going to talk about a class of car or anything like that. I want to talk about an own script.

What is the difference between using public or private for the programmer and the owner of the script.

if the script is a calculator, and I am the only one who will meinten the code in the future. when do I have to use private variables of methods. How this is going to change anything in the script?

Also, If it's about touching the variable ? if anyone tries to change the value, and he couldn't because of the private thing. He will go directly to change it using the setters ?

I need a good example that I can see private methods or variables have good benefits for programmer or the end user.

I was programming some scripts, and a guy told me to not use `var` in classes. I asked him why ? he said that you have to use public or private .. and asked why ?

Why to use setter if there is a way to change the variable directly?

Why to use getter if there is a way to change the variable directly?

Comment: These are basic questions which can be found in any book of oop. As for var, it was an old custom. Hence he forbade you. Try asking some specific question which isn't easily answerable in books or google.

Comment: [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)). [Mutator methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method). [Object Oriented PHP](http://php.net/oop).

Comment: So, you don't know the answer. Each book says that use private when you want to keep the variable inside the class. ? but why I need to keep it inside the class. ?

Comment: Too prevent modification which is undesired?

Comment: Use `private` when the property should only be accessible by instances of the class that defines it. Use `protected` when the property should only be accessible by the class that defined it and by classes that extent that class. Use `public` when the property should be accessible to anyone. Whether or not you should use mutators is a matter of choice/circumstance. There are pros and cons.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, when you're developing strong-OO classes, you should be exposing as little of the internal semantics of your class as possible (obviously without affecting functionality).

Some variables are only valuable inside the context of the class itself, and would make no sense to a developer using the class. Making the variable public allows anyone using the class to change such a variable at will, despite the fact that they may not know what it's used for. In PHP this can be a particular problem when you don't even have type safety to at least mitigate the damage that can be done.

Consider this: You have a class which wraps around some I/O operations. Let's call it `FileReader`

```
class FileReader {
    public $_handle;

    public function __construct($filepath) {
        $this->_handle = fopen($filepath, 'r');
        if ($this->_handle === NULL) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to open the file for reading");
        }
    }

    // ... the rest of the class
}
```

Now you can see that the class opens up a handle to a file. By making the `$_handle` variable public, you've exposed it to any and all people working on your class. They don't need to know about the raw file handle you have open, they just want to use your nice class to perform some read operation. However, it IS public; not only can they see it, but they can change it. This is bad, especially when your other code assumes that the `$_handle` variable is valid.

```
$reader = new FileReader();
$reader->_handle = "I hope this doesn't break anything. /trololol";
$reader->someOperation(); // oh no! Our file handle has just been changed to something completely wrong, this is now going to the break the class.
```

Such ridiculous scenarios can be avoided entirely by making the variable private in the first place. For more (and better) example of what each access modifier does, and when to apply them see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected).

Now, onto getters and setters. In your question, you seem to assume that all getters and setters are written the following way:

```
class Foo {
    private $_bar;

    public function getBar() {
        return $this->_bar;
    }

    public function setBar($newBar) {
        $this->_bar = $newBar
    }
}
```

In which case, you're absolutely right there is no difference between that and changing the `$_bar` variable to be public in the first place.

However, getter and setter methods give you control over **how** your variables are being set by an external developer, so you can instantly detect when they're going to make a boo-boo and avoid undefined behaviour later on. For example:

```
class Foo {
    private $_bar;

    public function getBar() {
        return $this->_bar;
    }

    public function setBar($newBar) {
        // Now we're going to ensure that $newBar is always an integer
        if (!is_int($newBar)) {
            // not an integer, throw out an exception to let the developer know that somewhere is setting invalid input
            throw new Exception("Expected an integer value for 'Bar'");
        }
        $this->_bar = $newBar;
    }
}
```

This is not only making your class far more robust, but also making the life of the developer using your class a hell of a lot easier. Rather than having to debug an extremely weird issue somewhere later on when the class attempts to use the corrupt value of `$_bar`, they can easily tell from a stack trace where the corrupt value was set from and fix it at the source.

There is plenty of documentation about variable access and getter/setter methods out there, and it applies to a whole range of languages so don't be afraid to look up articles that were based on C++/C#/VB.NET, they all roughly translate to the same material.

Comment: Nicely balanced answer, not just "because doing it differently is stupid".

Answer (score 1):

The end user doesn't see the code, so there's no (dis)advantage there.

For the programmer, declaring things that aren't needed outside the object as `private` is just a good programming practice and a protection mechanism. Technically, if you're a perfect programmer, and you don't care about how your code looks, using `private` will provide you no benefits. However, private members enforce the black box model -- you only care about what the object does, not about how it works (when looking at it from the outside). In the end, if for any reason you (or somebody else) needs/wants to use your code, they'll know what methods and properties to use/invoke in order to get the **functionality** the object has, without modifying the internal values the object needs to maintain. It may or may not give you any advantage -- it's just about how the code looks like. That's what good programming practices are for, and they are usually followed because experience says they tend to minimize errors.

As for `var`, it was deprecated. Meaning it could (and will) be removed in the future.

Comment: +1 for actually answer the part of the question about `var`

Answer (score 0):

Public, Private and Protected only matter in PHP if they are part of a function, or part of a class.

If you wanted to set a variable once and "lock it" so the value couldn't be changed later you can `define` it or set it as a `const` (constant).

> public scope to make that variable/function available from anywhere,
>   other classes and instances of the object.
>
> private scope when you want your variable/function to be visible in
>   its own class only.
>
> protected scope when you want to make your variable/function visible
>   in all classes that extend current class including the parent class.

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php