# PHP sharing code

Tags: php, share

I have a class file and within the class file some code.
How can I share the code across multiple pages.
The code tackles the use of fetching a resultset when using a prepared statement

The code is like this. How can I reuse the function mps_fetch_assoc. I want the code only on one place.

```
<?php

//http://localhost:8080/altenaontw/index.php?-action=showclient
class actions_showclient
{

    // find here http://www.meetup.com/austinphp/messages/boards/thread/2022681
    private function mps_fetch_assoc(&$stmt)
    {
        $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
        $retval[] = &$stmt;
        $tmp;
        $names;
        while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
        {
            $names[] = $field->name;
        }
        $tmp = $names;
        for ($c = 0; $c < count($names); $c++)
        {
            $retval[] = &$tmp[$c];
        }
        call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_result", $retval);
        if ($stmt->fetch())
        {
            $assoc_array;
            for ($c = 0; $c < count($names); $c++)
            {
                $assoc_array[$names[$c]] = $retval[$c + 1];
            }
            return $assoc_array;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    function handle($params)
    {
        header('Content-type: text/json; charset="UTF-8"');
        $user = Dataface_AuthenticationTool::getInstance()->getLoggedInUser();
        if (!$user)
        {
            return Dataface_Error::permissionDenied("U heeft geen toegang tot deze actie.");
        }

        $db = Dataface_Application::getInstance()->_conf['_database'];
        echo ($db['host']);

        //$mysqli = new mysqli($db['host'], $db['user'], "", $db['name']);
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect($db['host'], $db['user'], "", $db['name']);
        /* check connection */
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
        {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit();
        }

        $sql = 'SELECT * from client';
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        if ($stmt)
        {
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            if (!$result)
            {
                echo "[" . json_encode(array('dberror' => 'db_error:' . mysql_error())) . "]";
                return;
            }

            $rows = array();
            while ($row = $this->mps_fetch_assoc($stmt))
            {
                $rows[] = $row;
            }

            print json_encode($rows);
            $mysqli->close();
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Take care when formatting your code: make it easy to read, even for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

u have to use include(). see here:
[phpnet include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<?php include 'name_of_file.php'; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You should include your class file in any page you want to use the class. You may do this the following way:

```
<?php include 'file_to_include.php'; ?>
```

Afterwards, whenever you plan on calling the function **without** creating a new object you should do something like this:

```
<?php actions_showclient::mps_fetch_assoc($variable); ?>
```

If you will add a "__construct" function to your class, you can call the function in a different way, but I suggest you try taking a few lessons on www.codeacademy.com . They will teach you the basics of using classes.

Also, please make sure you want your function to be **private**, as this has certain effects on when you are able to call it (check this for more information: [What is the difference between public, private, and protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected)).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Another good way to do this could be class autoloading, saves having many many include()'s in a single file to get everything to work.

See here for more into:http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php