# accessing class variables from extended class with getter and setters

Tags: php, class, extends

Im trying to access a variable from one class through another class from a php script:

My first class is:

class data{

```
  private $length;
  private $height;      

   public function setLength($length){
    $this->length = $length;
   }

   public function getLength(){
    return $this->length;
   }

  public function setHeight($height){
    $this->height = $height;
   }

   public function getHeight(){
    return $this->height;
   }

}
```

I have another class:

```
class proccess extends data{

   public function getOrientation(){
      if($this->getLength() > $this->getHeight()) {
       $orientation = 'landscape';
      } else {
      $orientation = 'portrait';
   }

   }
```

}

When trying to access $this->getLenght() or $this-getHeight() from class process the values are empty; I am setting the values through my php script as so:

```
<?php


  require_once('functions/data.php');
  require_once('functions/process.php');

  $data=new data();
  $process = new process();

  $data->setLength(25);
  $data->setHeight(30);
  $orientation = $process->getOrientation();
```

Any ideas on why the function getOrientation is not able to get the value of width and length and how i can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting values for a different object which is `$data`. You have to set them for `$process`.

```
  $process = new process();

  $process->setLength(25);
  $process->setHeight(30);
  $orientation = $process->getOrientation();
```

Answer (score -1):

The variables should be `protected` not `private` - see these:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php
[What is the difference between public, private, and protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected)

And, as pointed out by MahanGM, you are using two different instances of objects, that aren't related to each other at all.  You should either be doing `$process->setLength` and `$process->setHeight` or `$data->getOrientation`.

Comment: Do they need to be protected? `process` only uses the public methods of `data` in the example, so it wouldn't need to be able to access `$length` or `$height` directly.

Comment: No, as long as the properties are always accessed through the getters and setters `setFoo()` and `getFoo()` the variables should stay `private`