# Yii extending the Controller function

Tags: php, yii, extend, overriding

What I need to do is to extend the `getPageTitle()` function so the titles to be translated and the `action` and `controller` swapped
This is the function I placed in the Controller.php

```
private $_pageTitle;
public function getPageTitle()
{
    if($this->_pageTitle!==null) {
            return Yii::t('wm', $this->_pageTitle);
    } else {
            $controller = Yii::t('wm', ucfirst(basename($this->getId())));

            if($this->getAction()!==null && strcasecmp($this->getAction()->getId(),$this->defaultAction)) {
                    $action = Yii::t('wm', ucfirst($this->getAction()->getId()));
                    return $this->_pageTitle=Yii::app()->name.' - '.Yii::t('wm', '{action} {controller}', array('{action}' => $action, '{controller}' => $controller));
            } else {
                    return $this->_pageTitle=Yii::app()->name.' - '.$controller;
            }
    }
}
```

reference from here: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/22258-internationalisationtranslation-of-page-title/

But if in the view I set a new custom title with anything of these

```
  $this->pageTitle = 'Title';
  $this->setPageTitle('Title2');
  Yii::app()->getController()->pageTitle="Title3";
```

**the title does not get changed**

If I check `parent::getPageTitle()` it always return value

If I check `$this->_pageTitle` it always return null

Answer (score 0):

`private` variables are only accessible in the class in which they are created, in your case `Controller`.

You should use `protected` instead since these variables are also accessible in all classes that inherit from the class in which it was declared.

For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361582/428543 and http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a private issue, since the private property is only referenced in this class.  I think you've assumed that getPageTitle() will be called when pageTitle is referenced as a Controller property.  But this may only hold true in model/activerecords.

This "call a function named get+PrivatePropertyName if outside code references propertyName and it's not publicly accessible" isn't a PHP feature and I don't think it's automatic in Controller.  You'd have to write your own __get() accessor to have this function called automatically.

(In the link you referenced, I only saw examples explicitly calling the getter and setter.)