# How to call one controller function in another controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one controller named `home.php` in which a function named `podetails` is there. I want to call this function in another controller `user.php`.
Is it possible to do so? I have read about `HMVC` in CI, but I want to know is it possible to do without using hmvc?

Comment: explain with example and use

Comment: I have explained it very clearly. Please read the question again.

Comment: please specify what is the use?

Comment: I just want to use that function in user.php controller. thats it.

Comment: Suppose function is in first controller what is the use of recall it in another controller?

Comment: its my project requirement. its nothing related to "use of the function"

Comment: You should not do that, anyway, and besides you cannot without HMVC, in the current CI's structure. You could always redirect, though

Comment: So you are using common code for both controllers. Then you make it as library function / or helper function. You can call anywhere in project.

Comment: Or extend your controller and make a method there (I do it this way).

Comment: @Kyslik can I have an example please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To extend controller please either follow this [tutorial](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY) or see some code below.

---

differences between [private/public/protected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361582/1564365)

---

make a file in folder `/application/core/` named `MY_Controller.php`

Within that file have some code like

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    protected $data = Array(); //protected variables goes here its declaration

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE); // I keep this here so I dont have to manualy edit each controller to see profiler or not        
        $this->load->model('some_model'); //this can be also done in autoload...
        //load helpers and everything here like form_helper etc
    }

    protected function protectedOne() {

    }

    public function publicOne() {

    }

    private function _privateOne() {

    }

    protected function render($view_file) {

        $this->load->view('header_view');
        if ($this->_is_admin()) $this->load->view('admin_menu_view');

        $this->load->view($view_file . '_view', $this->data); //note all my view files are named <name>_view.php
        $this->load->view('footer_view');

    }

    private function _isAdmin() {

        return TRUE;

    }

}
```

and now in any of yours existing controllers just edit 1st or 2nd line where

```
class <controller_name> extends MY_Controller {
```

and you are done

also note that all your variables that are meant to be used in view are in this variable `(array) $this->data`

example of some controller that is extended by `MY_Controller`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class About extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function index() {
        $this->data['today'] = date('Y-m-d'); //in view it will be $today;
        $this->render('page/about_us'); //calling common function declared in MY_Controller
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

write the **podetails()** as a function within a helper file.

then load that helper in both of the controllers.

in the controller you just call podetails()

Suppose:

--controller 1--

```
function podetails()
{
   podetails(); // will call function in helper ;
}
```

--controller 2--

```
function podetails()
{
   podetails(); // will call function in helper ;
}
```