# calling x controller function inside a y controller function codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I'm new to codeigniter and I have two controllers: `utility.php`and `welcome.php`.

In `utility.php`, I have functions:

```
   function getdata() {
     //code here
   }

   function logdata() {
     //code here
   }
```

Inside `welcome.php`, I have this function:

```
   function showpage() {
     //some code here
     //call functions here
   }
```

What I want to do is inside my `welcome.php`, I want to call the functions from `utility.php`. How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refrence from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21112202/1794539)

To extend controller please either follow this [tutorial](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY) or see some code below.

---

differences between [private/public/protected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361582/1564365)

---

make a file in folder `/application/core/` named `MY_Controller.php`

Within that file have some code like

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    protected $data = Array(); //protected variables goes here its declaration

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE); // I keep this here so I dont have to manualy edit each controller to see profiler or not        
        $this->load->model('some_model'); //this can be also done in autoload...
        //load helpers and everything here like form_helper etc
    }

    protected function protectedOne() {

    }

    public function publicOne() {

    }

    private function _privateOne() {

    }

    protected function render($view_file) {

        $this->load->view('header_view');
        if ($this->_is_admin()) $this->load->view('admin_menu_view');

        $this->load->view($view_file . '_view', $this->data); //note all my view files are named <name>_view.php
        $this->load->view('footer_view');

    }

    private function _isAdmin() {

        return TRUE;

    }

}
```

and now in any of yours existing controllers just edit 1st or 2nd line where

```
class <controller_name> extends MY_Controller {
```

and you are done

also note that all your variables that are meant to be used in view are in this variable `(array) $this->data`

example of some controller that is extended by `MY_Controller`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class About extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function index() {
        $this->data['today'] = date('Y-m-d'); //in view it will be $today;
        $this->render('page/about_us'); //calling common function declared in MY_Controller
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't is the short answer.

The point of MVC is to have your code well organized.

What you can do though is create a library in the libraries folder where you put methods you need in more than one controller.

For example you can make a mylog library, where you can put all your log related stuff. In any controller you will then call:

```
$this->load->library('mylog');
$this->mylog->logdata();
```

Besides functions that deal with data models should reside in models. You can call any model from any controller in CI

Answer (score 0):

That is out of concept, if you want to call code in different controllers do following:

1. create helper and call function whenever (even in view) you want.
2. extend CI_Controller so you can use one or more functions in any controller that is extended.

---

Lets start with helper:

create file in folder `application/helpers/summation_helper.php`

use following sample of code

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function sum($a, $b) {

    //$CI =& get_instance(); 
    // if you want to use $this variable you need to get instance of it so now instead of using $this->load... you may use $CI->load
    $return = $a + $b;
    return number_format($return, 3);

}
```

If you are going to use your helper in many controllers/views please load it in autoload, otherwise just load it manualy `$this->load->helper('summation');`

Extending `Controller_CI`: this is way better approach if you are using database. Please follow this [tutorial](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY), which explains it all.

*I have crafted an answer just before site went down posting this from cellphone.