# Two PDO connection error

Tags: php

Hey guys i have recently moved over to PDO and OOP and having some problems with the connection statement. The errors i am receiving are;

Notice: Undefined variable: db_host in C:\Users\PC\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\libs\class.Manage.php on line 14

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\Users\PC\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\libs\class.Manage.php on line 14

```
class ManageHits{

protected $link;
protected $db_host = "localhost";
protected $db_name = "ajaxrating";
protected $db_user = "userone";
protected $db_pass = "passwordone";

function __construct(){
    try{
    $this->link = new PDO($this->$db_host,$this->$db_name,$this->$db_user,$this->$db_pass);
        return $this->link;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        return $e->getMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read a step by step tutorial about PDO

Furthermore your code has many issues.

1. $e->getMessage; => $e->getMessage();
2. constructor should be [public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected) I assume ?
3. your variables should be [private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected)
4. constructors serve to instantiate the class
5. PDO
6. initialize your variables inside the constructor for compatibility

This is a working example assuming your connection info is correct:

```
class Con{

    protected $link;
    protected $db_host;
    protected $db_name;
    protected $db_user;
    protected $db_pass;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->db_host = "localhost";
        $this->db_name = "ajaxrating";
        $this->db_user = "userone";
        $this->db_pass = "passwordone";        

        try{

            $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
            echo 'Connection established!';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

$db = new Con();
```

Comment: thank you very much, will have to partake on a Youtube series on OOP and PDO

Answer (score 0):

1. Read at least *any* tutorial on PDO.
2. Connect to PDO proper way, creating a PDO instance.
3. Pass that instance in your ManageHits class.

   ```
   class ManageHits{

       protected $link;

       function __construct($db){
           $this->link = $db;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly calling your objects inside of `new PDO()`:

```
$this->$db_host
```

should be

```
$this->db_host // and so forth
```