# scope of private functions in extended php class

Tags: php

```
<?php

class Foo {
    private function FooFunction(){

      }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function BarFunction(){
           $this->FooFunction();
       }

}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->FooFunction();  //Fatal error: Call to private method Foo::FooFunction()
                      //(Fair enough)

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->BarFunction();  //Fatal error: Call to private method Foo::FooFunction()
                      //from context 'Bar'
```

I'm having some difficulty understanding how to properly declare functions in a class which can then be used in an extension of that class

When I instantiate Foo I'd like FooFunction to remain private.
However, I do need to be able to call it from within Bar.

Comment: Then use `protected`

Comment: Private only me, Protected my child can access, Public whole world can access.

Comment: From [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected): http://i.stack.imgur.com/SFysv.jpg

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 2):

change code as below:

```
<?php

class Foo {
    protected function FooFunction(){

      }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function BarFunction(){
           $this->FooFunction();
       }

}
```

`private` methods not accessable in child class.
you need to use `protected` method type.

Comment: You should probably also explain why.