# Function scope is out of class php

Tags: php

I want to know what is the scope that function who is out of class. Is it private, public or protected ?

```
function abc {
   //code here
}

class xyz {
 function car () {
   // code here 
 }
}
```

Now what is the abc function scop ?

Please help me

Comment: Everything declared in global namespace has "GLOBAL" scope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions outside any class are global an can be called from anywhere. The same with variables.. just remember to use the global for the variables...

e.g

```
<?php
function abc() {  }

$foo = 'bar';

class SomeClass {  
 public function tada(){
     global $foo;

     abc();
     echo 'foo and '.$foo;
 }
}
?>
```

functions are defined at a global level ; so, you don't need to do anything to use them from a method of your class.

For more informations, see the [function page in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php), which states (quoting) :

All functions and classes in PHP have the global scope - they can be called outside a function even if they were defined inside and vice versa.

If a "function" is defined inside a class, it's not called a "function" anymore, even if it is still the function that is used : it is called a "method"

Methods can be used statically :

```
MyClass::myMethod();
```

Or Dynamically :

```
$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->myMethod();
```

Depending on whether they were defined as static or not.

Comment: what is that public, private or protected ?

Comment: @user3425009  functions outside any class are global an can be called from anywhere. The same with variables.. just remember to use the global for the variables...

Comment: @user3425009 I have edited my answer, perhaps this will help you.

Comment: and obviously the scope is public for every class, because its available for every class, irrespective of hierarchy

Answer (score -1):

```
function abc {
   //code here
}
```

This is a public function because function scope mainly in class and in your case `abc`
not inside a class so it behave as a public function

`public` scope to make that variable/function available from anywhere, other classes and 
instances of the object.

`private` scope when you want your variable/function to be visible in its own class only.

`protected` scope when you want to make your variable/function visible in all classes that extend current class including the parent class.

reference  [What is the difference between public, private, and protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected)

Comment: is it use in class also ? if it is public.

Comment: you can use in class but define wheteher it is public or private by the use of public,private keyword

Comment: How can i use it? it is not in class and class is not extend any other class no one can use it in class... I thing this is private

Comment: you can test this by include this class file then call abc from source file it will call