# Access Protected Function Clarification in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I apologize if this is duplicate Question.
I have a protected function. For example.

```
protected function example(){
//some code
}
```

and i would like to access this function from 
outside the class. And i came up with the following.

```
public function returnMyFunction(){
  return $this->example();

}
```

What i would like to know if this is a correct way to do this. Thank you!

P.S 
I forgot to mention that i came up with that because in zend framework 2 i cannot extend the class that this function is in since the class i am calling it from is extending another

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected

Comment: What's the purpose of protected then?

Comment: Yes well that is what i want to know. If by doing that the protected purpose is lost. I forgot to mention that i came up with that because in zend framework 2 i cannot extend the class that this function is in since the class i am calling it from is extending another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually a protected method is protected because it is **not intended** to be accessed outside the class and its childs. Summary:

The intention for private methods is that they will never be accessed from outside the class.
The intention for protected ones, is that they will enver be accessed from outside the **class hierarchy** (declaring class and its descendants).
The intention for public methods is that they will be accessed from anywhere.

So, if you want to access the method outside a class, you should declare what you are declaring: an intermediate method (perhaps the intermediate public method performs a pre/post processing of the protected method). Another alternative to access it **exceptionally** (it's a hack! if you want to allow regular access, make it public instead) is to use `Reflection` (setting accessible = true), althought it is a bit slow.