# Private property error on insert PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have my class with private property, but at insertion it does not insert anything. 
Fields are empty.
Why is this happening?
the magic method does not treat my values?

My class:

```
class Test extends Model {

  protected $table = 'test';
  private $name;
  private $email;

  public function __get($var) {
    return $this->$var;
  }

  public function __set($var, $values) {
    return $this->$var;
  }

  public function insert() {

    $sql    = "INSERT INTO {$this->table} (name, email) VALUES (:name, :email)";
    $stmt   = DB::prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $this->email);
    return $stmt->execute();

  }

}

$name               = 'Michael';
$email              = 'test@test.com';
$test               = new Test();
$test->name         = $name;
$test->email        = $email;

$test->insert();
```

Comment: You need to read up on what public and private mean *before* you try to use them.

Comment: I wanted to work private.

Comment: Because you aren't setting them.... Take a look at your `__set()` method and tell me if you see something odd (*&There's your trivial task for the day*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer to the scope of your question. Your issue lies within the `__set()` method.

You notice how you aren't actually "setting" anything? rather just running it as you would the `__get()` method? (*returning the `$var`*).

What you want it to look like is this:

```
public function __set($var, $values) {
    $this->$var = $values;
}
```

Notice how we finally assign something there?! That's the magic you want, **and** need.

[**Example**](https://eval.in/175049)

---

**Foot-notes**

Please read [`John Conde's comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110801/private-property-error-on-insert-php/25110907#comment39078550_25110801), to prevent coding yourself into some ugly holes.

Comment: @Mourinha No worries, [`This`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4361553/2518525) Will be a great resource for you in relation to Public vs Private vs Protected.