# Let $this refer to the class that was initialized and not to the class it was coded in

Tags: php, inheritance

I have a function in a parent class that calls several functions in the parent class using `$this->functionName()`.
In a child I override functionName. When I run it still calls as if it was `parent::functionName()`:

```
class Foo {

    function MainCall(){
        $this->Bard();
    }

    private function Bard(){
        echo "HI";
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {

    private function Bard(){
        echo "bye";
    }
}

$dnew = new Bar();
$dnew->MainCall();
```

The above code run and echos "HI" but I want bye.

Comment: you want to use `protected` not `private`, see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected

Comment: You could just overwrite the `MainCall` method as well.