# Why doesn't derived class's function get called through base in PHP?

Tags: php, c++, oop, inheritance, private

I wrote this simple example that demonstrates my problem. I've a Base class and Derived class. When I call derived class's `justdoit` function, it doesn't call derived class `doer` function, instead it calls base class's `doer` function.

Expected output:

```
Base::doer
Derived::doer
```

Actual output:

```
Base::doer
Base::doer
```

Code:

```
<?

class Base {
 public function justdoit() {
  $this->doer();
 }
 private function doer() {
  print "Base::doer\n";
 }
}

class Derived extends Base {
 private function doer() {
  print "Derived::doer\n";
 }
}

$b = new Base;
$b->justdoit();

$d = new Derived;
$d->justdoit();

?>
```

Here's this same code example in C++ and it works:

```
class A {
    public:
        void justdoit();
    private:
        virtual void doit();
};

void A::justdoit() {
    doit();
}

void A::doit() {
    std::cout << "A::doit\n";
}

class B : public A {
    private:
        virtual void doit();
};

void B::doit() {
    std::cout << "B::doit\n";
}

int main() {
 A a;
 B b;
 a.justdoit();
 b.justdoit();
}
```

Output:

```
A::doit
B::doit
```

Funny thing is if I change my original PHP example and replace `private function` with `protected function` it starts working:

```
<?

class Base {
 public function justdoit() {
  $this->doer();
 }
 protected function doer() {
  print "Base::doer\n";
 }
}

class Derived extends Base {
 protected function doer() {
  print "Derived::doer\n";
 }
}

$b = new Base;
$b->justdoit();

$d = new Derived;
$d->justdoit();

?>
```

Output:

```
Base::doer
Derived::doer
```

Does anyone know why PHP and C++ produce different results and why does changing `private` to `protected` in PHP makes it produce the same result as C++?

Comment: btw: do not use short tags unless you are looking for troubles

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski What are short tags? Never heard of that. (Sorry!)

Comment: Short tags in PHP means using `<?` instead of the full `<?php`

Comment: Could you explain why short tags are bad?

Answer (score 6):

See [What is the difference between public, private, and protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected) for a good discussion of public, protected, and private in PHP.

Here's my take:

The function `justdoit` is declared in the `Base` class.  When `doer` is declared `private` in the `Derived` class, it has no visibility outside the `Derived` class, not even to the `Base` class.  Hence, even though `justdoit` is executed on an instance of `Derived`, it executes the `doer` in `Base` because that's the only `doer` function that is visible to it.

Comment: Then how come it works in C++ where it's also private? How come the same OOP code example produces two different results in two different languages.

Comment: Your use of `virtual` might explain it.  As I understand it, when you declare a function `virtual` in C++, you're instructing the language to use the most derived function that matches the signature.

Comment: That could explain it. Do you know how to make virtual function in PHP for same effect?

Answer (score 3):

`private` methods can **only** be access by that class. `protected` methods can be access by child classes. By declaring `private function doer` you explicitly saying only instances of class can call that function.

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected)

Comment: Thanks but how come it works in C++ that has solid OOP foundation?

Comment: @bodacydo What makes you think C++ has a "solid OOP foundation"?

Comment: @imibis I mean C was without OOP and then C++ added OOP.

Comment: A different language is doing inheritance differently - OMG!

Answer (score 0):

***"Then how come it works in C++ where it's also private?"***

Here in your C++ code you are calling the derived version of the function.

```
$d = new Derived;
$d->justdoit();
```

This code will call the derived version of the "justdoit()", not the base,in C++ when we create virtual functions, a vtable is created which maintains and holds the address of the overwritten functions, and at the time of calling, based on the type of the object you are using to call, functions gets invoked.
Here,

```
$b = new Base;
$b->justdoit();
```

in this block, you are using base object, hence base version got called.

I hope your query got answered.