# PHP and Mysql Object oriented

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I only see "connected" on my screen and nothing else. How can I show the mysql table rows on the screen?

```
<?php
class db {
    private $conn;
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $baseName;
    private $port;

    function __construct($params=array()) {
        $this->conn = false;
        $this->host = 'localhost'; //hostname
        $this->user = 'fp0313'; //username
        $this->password = ''; //password
        $this->baseName = 'test'; //name of your database
        $this->port = '3306';
        $this->connect();
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->disconnect();
    }

    function connect() {
        if (!$this->conn) {
            $this->conn = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password); 
            mysql_select_db($this->baseName, $this->conn); 

            if (!$this->conn) {
                $this->status_fatal = true;
                echo 'Connection BDD failed';
                die();
            } 
            else {
                $this->status_fatal = false;
                echo 'Connected';
            }
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }

        function selectData()
    {
        $User = $bdd->getOne('SELECT stud_id, stud_voornaam, stud_achternaam FROM student'); // 1 line selection, return 1 line
        echo $User['stud_id'].'<br>'; // display the id
        echo $User['stud_voornaam'].'<br>'; // display the first name
        echo $User['stud_achternaam']; // display the last name
    }


    function disconnect() {
        if ($this->conn) {
            @pg_close($this->conn);
        }
    }
}
$bdd = new db(); // create a new object, class db()
?>
```

Comment: where have you called the method selectData ??

Comment: logic flaw: if your connection failed, then there is literally **NO** point in trying to select a db. you need to check for a successful connection FIRST.

Comment: This statement, `$User = $bdd->getOne('SELECT stud_id, ...`, where's your `getOne()` method? This variable `$bdd` is not available in the scope of your method. And this statement `@pg_close($this->conn);` is also wrong.

Comment: Please stop using mysql_* in new code. Not sure if your school teaches it, but stop going there. [This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Learn [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and especially [parameterized statements.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you don't really understand how PHP classes work, so I'll walk you through the basics of OOP PHP. A full answer would be too long to post as an answer, so I've just put a brief introduction, and links to more detailed explanations :)

### Properties

Properties are essentially variables associated with an instance of an object. There can also be static properties, which are associated with a class. Properties can be declared as public, private or protected. [Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected).

### Methods

Similar to properties in that they are associated with instances of classes or of the class itself, methods are just functions which are part of a class. Methods can also be static, and can also be declared public, private or protected. The same link as above applies to this.

### Magic Methods

PHP has some 'Magic methods'. These are just names for methods that are reserved for special functionality. For example, the `__construct` is a magic method, which is run when the object is initialized. `__clone` is also a magic method, which is run when the object is cloned. To define one of these, you simply define a method with the same name as the magic method, and that method will be run at specific points, eg for the `__construct`; when the object is created, for the `__clone` method, it will be run when the object is cloned. Also, just a note — you don't need to define all magic methods, you only need to define the ones that you wish to be used. [Read more...](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

### Other links relating to important parts of OOP PHP, which are less relevant to your situation, but that are still important to know

- [Extending classses](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php)
- [Class Abstraction](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)
- [Object Interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php)
- [Object Serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php)

### In Context

So now you understand the basics behind OOP PHP, lets dig into what the class you've provided in your question does!

**First lets look at this part:**

```
private $conn;
private $host;
private $user;
private $password;
private $baseName;
private $port;
```

This declares all the properties. The `private` means that these properties will be available only from this class, and not any extending classes (See above link on extending classes).

**Now lets look at this:**

```
function __construct($params=array()) {
    $this->conn = false;
    $this->host = 'localhost'; //hostname
    $this->user = 'fp0313'; //username
    $this->password = ''; //password
    $this->baseName = 'test'; //name of your database
    $this->port = '3306';
    $this->connect();
}
```

This does not take any parameters. You can pass in a parameter, but that will not be used, and if you pass in nothing, an empty array will be assigned to the variable $params, which has only a local scope, as it is part of a function.

As you now know, this function will be executed when the object is created, so this assigns values to some of the properties; it sets `$conn` to false, `$host` to 'localhost', ect. It then runs the `connect()` function (you can skip to that bit to see what that does)

Now let's look at this:
    function __destruct() {
        $this->disconnect();
    }
This defines the `__destruct` magic method, which is run when the object is destroyed, which usually occurs at the end of a script. In this case, the function simply runs the `disconnect()` function, which we'll get to later.

**Now this part:**

```
function connect() {
    if (!$this->conn) {
        $this->conn = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password); 
        mysql_select_db($this->baseName, $this->conn); 

        if (!$this->conn) {
            $this->status_fatal = true;
            echo 'Connection BDD failed';
            die();
        } 
        else {
            $this->status_fatal = false;
            echo 'Connected';
        }
    }

    return $this->conn;
}
```

This first checks to see if `$conn` is set to false (It uses the `!` (not) operator to reverse it, so the condition evaluates as true if the inverse of `$conn` is true.). If this is the case, there is no database connection yet, so it creates one using `mysql_connect()`, and assigns the connection to the `$conn` property. It then selects the database. It then checks to ensure that the connection was successful. If it was not, the `$status_fatal` property is set to `true`, "Connection BDD failed" is echoed, and the execution is stopped using `die`, and if the connection was successful,  the `$status_fatal` property is set to `false`, and the word 'Connected' is echoed. This is what you are seeing at the moment. The function then returns the `$conn` property.

As someone pointed out in the comments of your question, you may want to select the database *after* you establish that the connection was successful, as this means that you will not be trying to select a database when the connection failed.

**Now let's look at this part:**

```
    function selectData()
{
    $User = $bdd->getOne('SELECT stud_id, stud_voornaam, stud_achternaam FROM student'); // 1 line selection, return 1 line
    echo $User['stud_id'].'<br>'; // display the id
    echo $User['stud_voornaam'].'<br>'; // display the first name
    echo $User['stud_achternaam']; // display the last name
}
```

There is actually an error with this method. Since this is in a function, all variables have local scope, and to target class properties, you need to refer to `$this`. So when you use `$bdd`, it assumes that within that local scope, there is such a variable, so you need to pass that in as a parameter to the function.

Assuming that you have now fixed that error, and passed in an object as a parameter, that object's method `GetOne`is run. I cannot tell you what this does, because I do now know what the `$dbb` object contains. It's kind of difficult to explain what happens without knowing, so I guess I'll rewrite something similar, without that object. You should be able to figure out how to adapt this to your situation. Here is how it would work using a mysql query (Note: I'm using mysqli, which is what you *should* be using, as mysql_* functions are now depreciated.):

```
function SelectData() {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, "SELECT stud_id, stud_voornaam, stud_achternaam FROM student LIMIT 1");
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo $user['stud_id'] . "<br />\r\n";
    echo $user['stud_voornaam'] . "<br />\r\n";
    echo $user['stud_achternaam'];
}
```

This references the connection previously made, in the `mysqli_query()` method, which queries the database. The results are then stored in the `$result` variable. `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` is then used to convert that result set into an associative array, which is then echoed. The function in your object probably does something similar to this.

**Now let's look at this part:**

```
function disconnect() {
    if ($this->conn) {
        @pg_close($this->conn);
    }
}
```

This closes a database connection. I believe this to be an error, however, as you have previously created a mysql database connection, but the `pg_close()` is for postgreSQL. I believe what you wanted was `mysql_close()`.

### *"Okay... but I'm still getting the same result"*

When you create your object using `$bdd = new db()`, the constructor is called, which as we established before, calls the connect method, which echoes "connected" when a connection is established, so this well be echoed. But to display the results, you need to *call* the `selectData()` method, which you do using the `->` operator, like this `$bdd->selectData()`.

---

I tried explaining everything in a lot of detail, but if you don't understand something, feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor calls `this->connect`, which is why you get the "connected" message.  However, you never call selectData().

```
$bdd = new db(); // create a new object, class db()
$bdd->selectData();
```

You will also want to call $bdd->disconnect();

Comment: Hey thanks!! It worked but now i get this error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/ubuntu/workspace/database.php on line 46"

Line 46:   
function selectData()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT stud_id, stud_voornaam, stud_achternaam FROM student";
        $result = $this->myconn->query($sql);
        echo $User['stud_id'].'<br>'; 
        echo $User['stud_voornaam'].'<br>'; 
        echo $User['stud_achternaam']; 
    }
What does this mean?

Comment: @F0313 - pass $bdd as a parameter to selectData().  It is not in scope of that function

Answer (score 0):

You are just creating a new db-object with `$bdd = new db()` and as your code mentions you are echoing `Connected` if you are connected. If you want to do something, you have to run `$bdd->selectData()`  for example.

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the 'Connected' because you only created the object.

Using `$bdd->selectData();` will return the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

// Add this 2nd line

```
$bdd = new db();
$bdd->selectData();
```