# I am creating a PHP OOP Connection with Add Query

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I developed on Java Swing OOP so I am a little confused with a PHP OOP Techniques, they are the same in logic but not the same with syntax. Please help me with this, I need your specialties. Thank you all.

this is my index.php

```
<?php
require_once("DB.class.php");

$db = new DB("localhost", "root", "100510", "findersa_jfph_smart");

$db->select("t1.`sid` AS 'id', t1.`Title` AS 'title', t1.`JobDescription` AS 'content', t1.`Location_City` AS 'city', t1.`SalaryType` AS 'salary',
 t1.`EmploymentType` AS 'working_hours', t2.`CompanyName` AS 'company', t1.`JobRequirements` AS 'requirements', t1.`JobCategory` AS 'category', t1.`activation_date` AS 'date',
 t2.`PhoneNumber` AS 'contact_telephone'","`listings` AS t1
LEFT JOIN `users` AS t2
ON t1.`user_sid` = t2.`sid`","t1.`activation_date` BETWEEN '2016-02-02 00:00:00' AND '2016-05-02 23:59:59' AND t1.active = '1' AND t1.listing_type_sid = '6'
LIMIT 50000");

?>
```

this is my DB.class.php

```
<?php
class DB {

    public $host;
    public $user;
    public $pass;
    public $dbase;

    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $dbase) {

        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
        $this->dbase = $dbase;

        $conn = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbase);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

         echo "Connected Successfully!";
    }

    public function select($myCols, $myTable, $myQuery) {

        if (!isset($myQuery)) {
            $sql = "select " . $myCols . " from " . $myTable;
        } else {
            $sql = "select " . $myCols . " from " . $myTable . " from " . $myQuery;
        }

        $result = $this->conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            return "0 results";
        }

        $conn->close();
    }

}


?>
```

Sorry I can't get all the code in the box. But this is where i have a particular error:

```
$result = $this->conn->query($sql);
```

in DB.class.php.

Thank you. This is my first question here, please bear with me.

Comment: What is the error? What does `$sql` end up as?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object,

$sql end up  = "select " . $myCols . " from " . $myTable . " from " . $myQuery;

Comment: Assign `$conn = new mysqli` to `$this->conn = new mysqli`

Comment: Maybe typo here, `" from " . $myTable . " from " . $myQuery` should be `where`?

Comment: Thanks Bankzilla, it works, Thanks also chris85 I overlooked the "from" in $sql. My code is working now. :-D

Comment: @MichaelCoros in the future please include your error message(s) when posting.

Comment: @chris85, thank you for reminding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP declaring the variable in the class definition is not a requirement, it's more for readability. Although you can set the definition of public, protected, private and static.

You can assign variables to the class level by making references with the `$this` instance. If you're writing it as a static class you would make references with `self` instead.

With your current code the database connection is not available in the select method, this can be easily achieved by assigning it to the class level via `$this->conn = new mysqli();`. When a variables is defined as `$conn = new mysqli();` it's only accessible to the method that declares it.

Comment: If you need more understanding, [this question describes how the class hierarchy and references work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21902271/970057)