# Why does calling of test() function of Foo class (which extends Bar class) returns result mixed from both classes?

Tags: php, visibility, access-specifier

It may sound silly, but I'm new in PHP. I was learning from the documentation about access specifiers when I came to this section.

```
class Bar {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "Bar::constructor<br />";
    }
    public function test() {
        $this->PublicTest();
        $this->PrivateTest();
        $this->protectedTest();
    }
    public function PublicTest(){
        echo "Bar::testPublic<br />";
    }
    private function PrivateTest() {
        echo "Bar::testPrivate<br />";
    }
    protected function ProtectedTest() {
        echo "Bar::testProtected<br />";
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "Foo::constructor<br />";
    }
    public function PublicTest() {
        echo "Foo::testPublic<br />";
    }
    private function PrivateTest() {
        echo "Foo::testPrivate<br />";
    }
    protected function ProtectedTest() {
        echo "Foo::testProtected<br />";
    }
}

$myFoo = new Foo();
$myFoo->test();
```

?>

This produces output as:

```
Foo::constructor
Foo::testPublic
Bar::testPrivate
Foo::testProtected
```

Why does it prints from `Bar` class for `private` function while it prints from `Foo` class for `public` and `protected` function? Since, i don't have `test()` function in `Foo` class, it accesses the `test()` function from `Bar` class.

Where does `$this` pointer point to? Does it point to the function of `Foo` class or functions of `Bar` class? I'm really confused here. Can someone please explain this to me? Any help would be so much appreciated.

Comment: here is a similar thread that might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/php-public-private-protected

Comment: @brad Thanks... But that didn't clarify my doubt though. :(

Comment: private equals only that class can see it       public = anyone can see and access it protected means it and any class that extends it can see. I am not 100% sure but I believe Foo class is using its local copy of PublicTest and ProtectedTest.....

Comment: @brad I'm confused about $this pointer. When the control goes to test()  function,  where does $this pointer actually points and why?

Comment: $this is the current object....maybe                  self::PublicTest(); would yield what you are thinking it should when you make new Foo(); $this-> is referring to the current object you are making not the current class

Comment: It doesn't make much sense but, well, this is how the methods visibility is implemented in PHP. Using the terminology of C++, the protected and public methods in PHP are `virtual` (the version that is called matches the class of `$this`), the private ones are not (they match the class of the function that calls them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the visibility of each class/function.
When we call test() at first, using this:

```
$myFoo = new Foo();
$myFoo->test();
```

We call the test() inside **Bar** class, since **Foo** extends **Bar** and it uses test() of **Bar** because it's public and is visible in class **Foo**.
Now, inside foo() of **Bar** class, these 3 functions are called:

```
$this->PublicTest();
$this->PrivateTest();
$this->protectedTest();
```

Here, we are inside **Bar** class right now and hence it can see PrivateTest() and ProtectedTest() of it's own class only. Because the visibility of these functions are set to *Private* and *Protected*.
But in case of PublicTest(), it can see 2 functions. Because PublicTest() is set to *Public* visibility for both **Foo** and **Bar** class.
Here, *Public* function of **Bar** class is chosen although **Foo** class has its own PublicTest() because of following reason:

Since, we are using **$this** handler, which always reference to the object currently being used (which is of **Foo** class in this case), it chooses PublicTest() of **Foo** class.

Answer (score 0):

$this is the current object....maybe self::PublicTest(); would yield what you are thinking it should when you make new Foo(); $this-> is referring to the current object you made, not the current class –

```
class Animal {

     public function whichClass() {
        echo "I am an Animal!";
    }

   /* This method has been changed to use the 
       self keyword instead of $this
   */

    public function sayClassName() {
       self::whichClass();
    }

}

class Tiger extends Animal {

    public function whichClass() {
        echo "I am a Tiger!";
    }

}

$tigerObj = new Tiger();
$tigerObj->sayClassName();
```

this will produce I am an Animal!

this was taken from http://www.programmerinterview.com