# PHP Cannot access private property inside class

Tags: php, phalcon

I am getting an error in my server,

```php
<?php
class Encryption{
    private $_encryptionkey;
    public function setEncryption($key){
        $this->_encryptionkey = $key;
    }
}
```

when I call

```php
$enc = new Encryption();
$enc->setEncryption("abcd123");
```

I am getting error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property Encryption::$_encryptionkey
```

This error keep show event i change _encryptionkey to protected, but error gone if i change to public.

> My Server running PHP Version 7.1.0 using phalcon version 3.0.3

Comment: it's working:- https://eval.in/707425

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected read this

Comment: i wonder if its `phalcon` specific

Comment: its work on my computer but not working on server.

Comment: First, I found this issue on Phalcon's issues page, https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/3033 - not much information. I believe this is something of Phalcon rather than PHP.

Comment: thanks all, issue closed by change php version to 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Phalcon doesn't support PHP 7.1 so it's probably bug with Phalcon compilation for PHP 7.1

With PHP 7.0 you will don't have this problem.