# Shouldn't $this refer to the current object?

Tags: php, oop

I'm learning the differences between self, static and this and ran across this example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php):

```
<?php
class A {
    private function foo() {
        echo "success!\n";
    }
    public function test() {
        $this->foo();
        static::foo();
    }
}

class B extends A {
   /* foo() will be copied to B, hence its scope will still be A and
    * the call be successful */
}

class C extends A {
    private function foo() {
        /* original method is replaced; the scope of the new one is C */
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->test();
$c = new C();
$c->test();   //fails
?>
```

The result is

```
success!
success!
success!


Fatal error:  Call to private method C::foo() from context 'A' in /tmp/test.php on line 9
```

My question is this: when creating the new object C, shouldn't the call `$this->foo();` call the newly replaced private function foo inside class C (and return an error since it's private)?

Comment: Interesting! However, isn't the error message exactly what you expect it to be? The script tries to call C:foo() whereas the scope is within A, rightfully failling because foo() is now private to C. Or am I not undestanding what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `protected` rather than `public` to get this behaviour.

This is covered in a lot of detail here: [What is the difference between public, private, and protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected)

A quick excerpt:

> - public scope to make that variable/function available from anywhere, other classes and instances of the object.
> - private scope when you want your variable/function to be visible in its own class only.
> - protected scope when you want to make your variable/function visible in all classes that extend current class including the parent class.