# How to use variables from php file where require/include is declared

Tags: php, mysql

So basically, I have a config.php file for connecting to the mysql database, and a functions.php file that includes some functions. In all my files (eg. index, login, register), I use the line `require('config.php');` and inside config.php I have this line `require('functions.php');` for including the config + functions together using the line `require('config.php');` in my index, login, and register.php files.

So basically my problem is, the variables that I've declared in config.php are not recognized inside functions.php. How do I make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to learn about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very likely your functions don't work because their [scope does not include the variables you are trying to use](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

First, make sure `functions.php` is being included **after the variables are set**

Also, make your functions [Public Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected), OR, declare global variables inside functions by doing this:

```
$testVariable = "test";
function testFunction() {
     global $testVariable;
}
```

Comment: @Sadman If my answer helped you, make sure you check that little check button next to my answer to mark it as correct. Please and thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the *global* statement to declare variables inside functions as global variables.

```
function myfunction() {
  global $myvar;  // $myvar set elsewhere can be read within this function
                  // and if its value changes in this function, it changes globally
}
```

Comment: The `public` keyword is only for use in a class structure.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `global variavlename` or `$GLOBAL['variavlename without $']`

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    global $a;
    $a = $a + $GLOBALS['b'];
} 

Sum();
echo $a;
?>
```