# Accessing arrays in objects with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

How can I access the TXN_ID in the following object with PHP? Below is a print_r of the object:

```
$txn_object = $txn_params[last_payment];
error_log( print_r($txn_object,true) );
```

I get this in the error log:

```
EE_Payment Object
(
    [_props_n_values_provided_in_constructor:protected] => Array(
        [PAY_ID] => 4168
        [TXN_ID] => 746919
        [STS_ID] => PAP
        [PAY_timestamp] => 2017-08-29 14:06:26
        [PAY_source] => CART
        [PAY_amount] => 24.000
        [PMD_ID] => 11
        [PAY_gateway_response] => submitted_for_settlement
        [PAY_txn_id_chq_nmbr] => 96g71gxv
        [PAY_po_number] => 
        [PAY_extra_accntng] => 
        [PAY_details] => 
    )
)
```

I've tried a few things, but can't seem to get that value but comes back blank:

```
$txn_object->_props_n_values_provided_in_constructor[0]->TXN_ID
```

Comment: What error message you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using `print_r` to reverse-engineer objects and read the documentation/source.

You've got an `EE_Payment` object, which is part of the [Event Espresso](https://github.com/eventespresso/event-espresso-core) library. [The source of this class is available here](https://github.com/eventespresso/event-espresso-core/blob/master/core/db_classes/EE_Payment.class.php), and shows a method called `TXN_ID` to return the transaction ID.

```
$id = $txn_object->TXN_ID();
```

will get you what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access to `TXN_ID` element from outside of the Object (class), because the `_props_n_values_provided_in_constructor` property is `protected`.

> - public scope to make that variable/function available from anywhere,    other classes and instances of the object.
> - private scope when you want your variable/function to be visible in    its own class only.
> - protected scope when you want to make your variable/function visible    in all classes that extend current class including the
>     parent class.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361582/5465663

Take a look into into [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).