# Calling function from another file

Tags: php, wordpress

I need the `getdata()` function from `class-GetData.php` to call inside this `shortcode_function()`.

```
require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/class-GetData.php';

add_shortcode('registration-plugin','shortcode_function');    
function shortcode_function()
{
    ob_start();
    insert_data();
    getdata();   //from GetData.php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
?>
```

class-GetData.php

```
<?php

    class GetData
    {
       public function getdata()
       { 
          //something here
       }
    }

    $getData = new GetData();
```

But i am getting undefined function error:

> Call to undefined function getdata()

Comment: `getData()` is a *method* in the `GetData` class. You need to use `$getData->getData()`, call the method on the object. Usually, you wouldn't initialize the object in the class-file though

Comment: `$getData->getdata()`

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 1):

Use the object of GetData class to call the function created in the class.

```
require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/class-GetData.php';

add_shortcode('registration-plugin','shortcode_function');    
function shortcode_function()
{
    ob_start();
    insert_data();
    $getData = new GetData(); //Create Getdata object
    $getData->getdata(); //call function using the object
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

class-GetData.php

```
class GetData
{
   public function getdata()
   { 
      //something here
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps want to explain your answer a bit? What has been changed from the original code, and why did you change that? Always have some text to explain your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `Class Method` like as normal function calling. Inner `Class Method` need `this` keyword to call a method in a Class. If you want to call `Public` function/method from outside of the class, You have to create an `Object`.

> **Try to use -**

```
function shortcode_function(){
  ob_start();
  insert_data();
  $getData = new GetData(); #Create an Object
  $getData->getdata();      #Call method using Object
  return ob_get_clean();
}
```

> **Example :**

```
class GetData{
   public function getdata() { 
      //something here
   }

   public function TestMethod(){
      $this->getdata(); #Calling Function From Inner Class
   }
}

$getData = new GetData(); #Creating Object
$getData->getdata();      #Calling Public Function from Outer Class
```

> Here is the explanation for [`Private`,`Public` and `Protected`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected)

Comment: Or you can use like as `(new GetData())->getdata()`

Comment: Do you perhaps want to explain your answer a bit? What has been changed from the original code, and why did you change that? Always have some text to explain your answer. Why should anyone "*try to use*" this?

Comment: Ahh Yes! I am updating my answer. Thank you @Qirel