# $this->a give error but $this->a= 20; give output why?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    class Test
    {
        private $a = 10;
        public $b ='abc';



}
class Test2 extends Test
{

    function __construct()
    {

         echo $this->a;
         echo $this->a = 20; // wh
    }

}
$test3 = new Test2();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $this->a;
```

echoes value of class property `a`. This property is **not defined**, because property `a` of class `Test` is **private** and therefore is not available in class `Test2`. So, property `a` is created in class `Test2`.

```
echo $this->a = 20; // wh
```

does the next: assigns 20 to `a` property (which was created on the previous line) and echoes result of assignment which is `20`.

The solution:

```
class Test
{
        // protected property is avalilable in child classes
        protected $a = 10;
        public $b ='abc';
}

class Test2 extends Test
{
    function __construct()
    {
         echo $this->a;
         $this->a = 20;
         echo $this->a;
    }
}
$test3 = new Test2();  // outputs 10 20
```

Comment: Bleh. I close voted for the wrong reason. I should have duped this on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

You should change

```
private $a = 10;
```

to:

```
protected $a = 10;
```

Comment: Sure, but the question is "why"? You could learn a thing or two from [u_mulder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46745074/1415724).