# Call parent method that calls methods on itself?

Tags: php, oop

I'm having a strange issue with OOP PHP, methods on my child that call methods on the parent that set properties on itself don't seem to work.

For example:

**Child Class**

```
class B extends A {
    private function childMethod() {
        // Some code
        $this->parentClassMethod()
    }
}
```

**Parent Class**

```
class A {
    protected function parentClassMethod() {
        echo "Something here" // This will work
        $this->_someVariable = 'someValue'; // This will not
    }
}
```

I'm having a feeling this is probably the wrong way of doing this since it doesn't work, so any help would be great.

Comment: That's what happens when you use `private`. You probably want to read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `parent` instead of `$this`  but you can't call a `private` method in the parent from a child.

```
class A
{
    public $someVariable = '';
    public function parentClassMethod()
    {
         echo 'Something here';
         $this->someVariable = 'Some Value';
    }
}
class B extends A
{
    private function childMethod()
    {
        parent::parentClassMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also declare `parentClassMethod()` as `protected` instead of `private`. Please look at  [Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

```
<?php

class A {

    protected $_someVariable;

    protected function parentClassMethod() {
        echo "Something here";
        $this->_someVariable = 'somSomething is wrongue';
        echo $this->_someVariable;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private function childMethod() {
        // Some code
        $this->parentClassMethod();
    }
}

?>
```