# Cannot access private property

Tags: php

I have a problem with the following code, I am trying to print the data of a student but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property
>   Secretary::$students

If i put the attributes as public, it works correctly.

```
class Student {

    private $name;

    public function __construct($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

}

class Secretary{

    private $students = array();

     public function printStudents(){

         foreach($this->students as $key=>$value){
             echo $value->name . " ";
         }
     }

}

$secretary = new Secretary();

// Add students.
$student = new student("Student1");
array_push($secretary->students,$student);

$secretary->printStudents();
```

Comment: You're trying to access a private class member outside of your class. What do you expect to happen? Make it public or move that logic inside of that class.

Comment: You should also look at `array_push($secretary->students,$student);` You could add another method to `Secretary` to add a student.

Comment: why have `getName()` if you're not gonna use it outside the class to get the name? (this should answer your name problem)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between public, private, and protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Student->name is a private data member. That means, by definition, you cannot access it outside of the definition of Student. That's basically the purpose of `getName()`, so you CAN access it outside the definition.

What you want to do is this:

```
foreach($this->students as $key=>$value){
    echo $value->getName() . " ";
}
```

This will act as expected.

If you want to know more about access modifiers, you can read about them [here](https://phppot.com/php/php-access-modifiers/).

Answer (score 2):

You need a setter function for this. You cannot directly access a private variable.

In Class Secretary you need a function AddStudent(Student $students);

This function will look like:

```
public function AddStudent(Student $student) {
    if (!$this->students->contains($student)) {
        $this->students[] = $student;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Afterwards you can use your function 'printStudents' to printout all students.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access a private property of a class outside of its own scope. To achieve what you want, consider making a new method like so:

```
public function addStudent(Student $s): Secretary
{
    array_push($this->students, $s);
    return $this;
}
```

Then, you can append your new student to the Secretary.

```
$s = new Secretary();
$s->addStudent(new Student('Foo'));

$s->printStudents();
```

You can see a [live demo](https://3v4l.org/CYVG1) of it working.