# Why can child override and access its parent private method?

Tags: php, oop, overriding, visibility, private-methods

I'm used to put method as `protected` in my PHP classes. But playing with `private` I'm starting to have doubts.

I know that it might be a duplicate but I can't find clarity from the SO-answers I've read.
Checked the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) and [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected) but still my tests are incoherent with what is being said there (see below).

Especially is not often explained the kind of "tangling" among `public` and `private` method, when extending the same type class, in the context of PHP.

For example:

```
<?php

class A
{
    private function ab() { echo 'test'.PHP_EOL; }
    public function test() { $this->ab(); }
    public function accessprivate($obj)  { $obj->ab(); }
}

class B extends A
{
        public function ab() { echo 'overridden-public'.PHP_EOL; }  // expect notice overriding private parent method
}

$a = new A;
$a2 = new A;
$b = new B;

$a->test(); // expect 'test'
$b->test(); // expect access to B::ab() and print 'overridden-public'
$b->ab();   // expect access to B::ab() and print 'overridden-public'
$a2->accessprivate($a); // expect 'test' since is the same class
$b->accessprivate($a); // expect cannotaccess private of A from class B
```

When running this is the result:

```
test test overridden-public test test
```

The  main point is that I expected that **a `private` method is inherited but not accessible to child classes**; hence:

- I shouldn't be able to change the visibility of `ab()` to `public`
- with the override of `ab()` in `B` I would expect `test()` to call `ab()` on `$this` as `B` instance, and get printed *"overridden-public"*
- `accessprivate()` from `$a2` on `$a` is fine because they are the same class
- `accessprivate()` from `$b` on `$a` should NOT be fine because they are different classes (parent & child)

So the questions are:

- Why am I wrong? What am I misunderstanding?
- Is this visibility model the same on other languages or PHP is doing it differently? And in that case, are my expectation fitting more the visibility model of some other language?

Comment: You show the expected results in your question but not the actual results. Adding them might be helpful.

Comment: Added. Thank you for the suggestion 

Comment: Good question. It's indeed quirky. Sidenote: If you create a class C and define `public function accessprivate($obj)  { $obj->ab(); }` on it, you get the expected error. I am assuming that php's context gets still bound to A when you do `$obj->ab()` yet I have no clue why.

Comment: Other sidenote:  Your `public function ab()` on `B` is not overriding anything. It's creating a completely new method on `B`. (Other languages require the `override` keyword. Php lacks this so this can be confusing.) Having `A::ab()` private hence prohibits its parent call in `B`, so you cannot do `parent::ab()` within `B` due to private access.

Answer (score 4):

> I shouldn't be able to change the visibility of `ab()` to `public`

An overriding implementation must have the same *or higher* visibility in order to not violate the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). The overriding implementation doesn't expose the parent implementation, so no fundamental concern here. If the parent's implementation is non-public, for all intents and purposes it doesn't exist. For all intents and purposes the child is adding a new method to the class, which is fine.

> with the override of `ab()` in `B` I would expect `test()` to call `ab()` on `$this` as `B` instance, and get printed "overridden-public"

`private` methods are "hard bound" to the declaring class. `A::test` will call a `private` `A::ab` preferably. This is specifically so class internals can remain *`private`*. Should an extending class implement an identical method *unknowingly*, there's no surprising behaviour within `A`.

> `accessprivate()` from `$b` on `$a` should NOT be fine because they are different classes (parent & child)

It's still calling `A::accessprivate` since `B` doesn't implement any such method, which rather works the same as the `test` method and the explanation in the previous paragraph.

The purpose of `private` is largely to guarantee no interference from outside or extending code. If you're marking methods as `private`, you can be very sure which implementation of code will be called (always the declaring class), regardless of whether methods are overridden in children. If you keep this in mind, the behaviour is pretty expected and self-explanatory. `protected` methods explicitly allow and expect overriding to take place and behave accordingly.

Comment: Mmmh, still processing it; but it starts to make sense, thank you – Still, it's tricky since this looks like an implicit behaviour, while I would rather expect to get a *notice*, in case I am doing something that I am not allowed to do (or that will sort no effect, like the non-working overriding of my examples). On this concern, the PHP documentation didn't appear much clear. Is this behaviour explicitly documented/mentioned anywhere on php.net ?