# How to pass parameters to add_feed in an OOP singleton

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I struggle creating separate page feeds (list of URLs) in each language when WPML is active.

The plan is to have different feed names for each language, such as `feed_name_en` or `feed_name_fr`.

I wrote the following function that iterates through each available language on the site and should output a feed for each language containing only the pages in the particular language.

I found other examples that show how to pass parameters within `add_action` using closures. (eg. `add_action('init', function() use($param) { some_out_of_scope_function($param) } )`

But in my function I am getting the following error:

> Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in

I have the suspicion that it is because I am using OOP to encapsule the function in an array `add_feed( $feedname, array( $this, ... ) )`. But I have no idea how to work around this.

How shall I approach this?

```
$feedname = 'feed_name'; 

private function createLanguageFeeds(){

    foreach($this->wpml_languages as $lang){

        // add the lang to the feed name. example: feed_name_en
        $feedname = $this->feedname . '_' . $lang;

        // making sure that the feed is created
        if ( ! in_array( $feedname, $wp_rewrite->feeds ) ) {
            $wp_rewrite->feeds[] = $feedname;
            flush_rewrite_rules( FALSE );
        }

        add_feed( $feedname, array( $this, function() use ($lang) {$this->create_page_feed($lang);} ) );
    }
}

private function create_page_feed($lang){
    // echo pages
}
```

Comment: Unrelated issue: your `create_page_feed()` function needs to be `public` instead of `private`, otherwise WordPress won't be able to access it. See [What is the difference between public, private, and protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.4 or newer, you can just pass the closure with the `$lang` parameter to the `add_feed()` function and `$this` will retain the reference to the object:

```
add_feed( $feedname, function() use ($lang) {$this->create_page_feed($lang);} );
```

Note that your `create_page_feed()` method needs to be `public` so WordPress can access it:

```
public function create_page_feed($lang){
    // echo pages
}
```

(see [What is the difference between public, private, and protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected) for more details.)

Here's a tested & working demo plugin that registers a feed using the Singleton pattern:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name:       Singleton RSS Feed
 * Plugin URI:        https://cabrerahector.com
 * Description:       A demo RSS feed built using the Singleton pattern.
 * Version:           1.0.0
 * Author:            Hector Cabrera
 * Author URI:        https://cabrerahector.com/
 * License:           GPL-2.0+
 * License URI:       http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
 * Text Domain:       singleton-rss-feed
 * Domain Path:       /languages
 */

class Singleton_RSS_Feed
{
    /**
     * The unique instance of the plugin.
     *
     * @var Singleton_RSS_Feed
     */
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * Gets an instance of our plugin.
     *
     * @return Singleton_RSS_Feed
     */
    public static function get_instance()
    {
        if (null === self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    private function __construct()
    {
        // Actions
        add_action('init', array($this, 'createFeed'));
    }

    /**
     * Register the feed.
     */
    public function createFeed()
    {
        global $wp_rewrite;

        $feedname = 'some_rrs_feed';
        $lang = 'en';

        // Making sure that the feed is created
        if ( ! in_array( $feedname, $wp_rewrite->feeds ) ) {
            $wp_rewrite->feeds[] = $feedname;
            flush_rewrite_rules( FALSE );
        }

        add_feed( $feedname, function() use ($lang) {$this->renderFeed($lang);} );
    }

    /**
     * Renders the feed.
     *
     * @param string $lang
     */
    public function renderFeed($lang)
    {
        header( 'Content-Type: application/rss+xml' );
        ?>
        <xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
        <rss version="2.0">
            <channel><title>RSS Feed in <?php echo $lang; ?> language</title></channel>
        </rss>
        <?php
    }
}

$Singleton_RSS_Feed = Singleton_RSS_Feed::get_instance();
```

The feed will be available here: `https://www.example.com/feed/some_rrs_feed`.

Comment: Your solution showed me what I was missing. It was as simple as changing `add_feed( $feedname, array( $this, function() use ($lang) {$this->create_page_feed($lang);} ) );` to `add_feed( $feedname, function() use ($lang) {$this->create_page_feed($lang);} );`. I only don't understand why...

Comment: The reason is that when you use the first form (the array) WordPress expects the second item in the array to be a `string` (the name of the function to call), not a `function`. When WordPress tries to use your anonymous function as a string it fails with a "Object of class Closure could not be converted to string" message @alev. Hope that clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to @cabrerahector who pointed me to the right solution.

For those who want to see the corrected code of mine, here is the solution.

Simply the line

`add_feed( $feedname, array( $this, function() use ($lang) {$this->create_page_feed($lang);} ) );`

had to be changed to

`add_feed( $feedname, function() use ($lang) {$this->create_page_feed($lang);} );`

The full code would be:

```
$feedname = 'feed_name'; 

private function createLanguageFeeds(){

    foreach($this->wpml_languages as $lang){

        // add the lang to the feed name. example: feed_name_en
        $feedname = $this->feedname . '_' . $lang;

        // making sure that the feed is created
        if ( ! in_array( $feedname, $wp_rewrite->feeds ) ) {
            $wp_rewrite->feeds[] = $feedname;
            flush_rewrite_rules( FALSE );
        }

        add_feed( $feedname, function() use ($lang) {$this->create_page_feed($lang);} );
    }
}

private function create_page_feed($lang){
    // echo pages
}
```