# Parent class always undefined

Tags: php, oop

I have a weird problem in PHP. I have two classes, one extending another. The problem is that i when I try to access a variable in the parent class (via a `getVar()` method), it returns `undefined`, even though it had been already defined in the parent's constructor.

```php
class HttpClient
{
    private $errorList;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $errorList = [];
    }

    public function getHttpErrorList() { return $errorList; }

    //...
}
```

```php
class Twitter extends HttpClient 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //..
    }

    public function getMessages()
    {   
        //...

        var_dump($this->getHttpErrorList()); //returns undefined variable!
    }
```

What is the cause of this problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: You didn't set `errorList`'s value.

Comment: You need to use `protected`, in this case:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected

Comment: @CoderCharmander i did define, sorry for the typo

Comment: `$errorList` is a property of the class, and not a local variable - so you need `$this->errorList` in the constructor and class-methods.

Comment: also are they in the same file? if not, you'll need require to include the class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining `$errorList=[]` inside your constructor is defining a local variable to the constructor. I.e. variable `$errorList` is undefined in method `getHttpErrorList()` - if you want access to `$errorList` at the object level, you need to change it to `$this->errorList` inside your constructor and in method `getHttpErrorList()`.

```
<?php
class HttpClient
{
    private $errorList;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->errorList = []; // change to $this->errorList
    }

    public function getHttpErrorList() { return $this->errorList; } // change to $this->errorList

    //...
}

class Twitter extends HttpClient
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //..
    }

    public function getMessages()
    {
        //...

        var_dump($this->getHttpErrorList()); //outputs array(0) {}
    }
}

$twit = new Twitter();
$twit->getMessages(); // output: array(0) { }
```