# How to add your skin, on the example of Elementor hello-world?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

https://code.elementor.com/methods/elementor-widget_base-_register_skins/

protected function _register_skins() { $this->add_skin( new Skin_Classic( $this ) ); }

If I just add this code, an error appears.
There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email email inbox for instructions.

Help me write a code for my widget skins.

Comment: You can check it

https://www.ibenic.com/extending-elementor-custom-button-field-skin/

Answer (score 0):

_register_skins is a protected function

That means you cannot call it.

[What is the difference between public, private, and protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected/21902271#21902271)

I hope this helps

Best,
Kaz