# PHP replace extends with another class when extending

Tags: php

Let's take the following class structure:

```
class A {
    ... has all the functionalities of A
}

class B extends A {
   ... has all the functionalities of A and B
}
```

And these two other class structures:

```
class C extends B {
   ... has all the functionalities of A and B and C
}

class D extends A {
    ... all the functionalities of A, and D
}
```

how could I create a class easily, that would gain all the functionalities of all four of my classes, if I am not allowed to modify `class A` or `class B`? Would something like this be possible with `PHP`?

**EDIT:**

The reason I would like to do this is the following, I am open for suggestions on other ways my desired outcome can be achieved:

I have a module, which has several classes on which I plan to build on, and I do not want to edit the module directly, but I would like to add functionalities potentially to multiple classes of this module (this is where `class A` and `class B` is coming from).

So to edit `class A`, I would create a `class D`, which extends it, and add new functionalities, or rewrite already added functionalities that needs rewrite in `class D`.

But there are multiple classes in this module, which are simmilar in structure to `class B`, which I would also like to potentially modify, hence my `class C`. But if I modified the modules `class A` in my `class D`, I would need my new `class C` to extend the `class D` instead of the `class A`. (hope you can still follow me:P)

Comment: Multiple inheritance in php is not available. But `D` can extend `C` and your new class can extend `D`. But I think this is a very poor design. Or your new class will extend `D` and you inject instance of `C` in it.

Comment: You can use protected class, any SO reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected)

Comment: @u_mulder I have edited my question, to show why I am contemplating on taking this path, but I am open to other advices on how to solve my problem...

Comment: What about using interfaces?

Comment: @B001ᛦ I don't see how interfaces would help me in this situation... would you elaborate on this please?

Comment: _would you elaborate on this please..._ Take a look at the SOLID principles. You will find out that inheritance is not always the best approach--almost never

Answer (score 2):

No, in PHP it is not possible to inherit from multiple parents due to "[Dimond Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)". In your case, this means you can extend `c` for the functionality of `a, b & c`, but you cannot extend `d` too. Since you cannot modify the other classes, there is not right solution here, but I'd recommend looking into traits (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), as these allow you to 'inherit' from multiple traits.

Comment: looks interesting, and maybe exactly what I need, I will look into it, and if it solves my issue, I will accept the answer