# Laravel get data out of foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

The below code shows the error (on the line `if ($response) {`):

> Undefined variable: response

I am checking the `if` condition inside the `foreach` because I wanted to check whether each `id` in the `UserEnabledNotifications` table exists in `notifications` table. Also `dump($response);` inside the `if` condition of `foreach` shows data.

Can I get the data in `$response` outside the `foreach` loop? What shall I try?

```php
$notificationData = UserEnabledNotifications::all();

foreach ($notificationData->where('status', 'true') as $user => $value) {
    if (Notifications::where('userEnabledNotificationsId', $value['id'])->exists() == false) {
        $notificationTypeName = NotificationTypes::where('id', $value['notificationTypesId'])
            ->value('notificationTypeName');

        $userData = User::where('id', $value['userId'])
            ->get()
            ->toArray();

        $data = [];

        $data['notificationTypesId'] = $value['notificationTypesId'];
        $data['notificationTypeName'] = $notificationTypeName;
        $data['userId'] = $value['userId'];
        $data['email'] = $userData[0]['email'];
        $data['recipientName'] = $userData[0]['FullName'];
        $data['userEnabledNotificationsId'] = $value['id'];

        $response = Notifications::create($data);
        //dump($response);

        $tags[] = $response;
    }
}

if ($response) {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'success',
        'data' => $tags,
        'statusCode' => 200,
        'status' => 'success'
    ], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `$response` in first if body but you need `$response = null` above that.

Answer (score 0):

You might create a private or protected variable, and put it outside, and then access it directly or via functions

```
$notificationData = UserEnabledNotifications::all();
private $reponse = null;

foreach ($notificationData->where('status', 'true') as $user => $value) {

   if(Notifications::where('userEnabledNotificationsId',$value['id'])->exists()==false){
                      
      $notificationTypeName = NotificationTypes::where('id', $value['notificationTypesId'])->value('notificationTypeName');
      
      $userData = User::where('id', $value['userId'])->get()->toArray();
      
      $data = [];
      $data['notificationTypesId'] = $value['notificationTypesId'];
      $data['notificationTypeName'] = $notificationTypeName;
      $data['userId'] = $value['userId'];
      $data['email'] = $userData[0]['email'];
      $data['recipientName'] = $userData[0]['FullName'];
      $data['userEnabledNotificationsId'] = $value['id'];
      $response = Notifications::create($data);
      
      $tags[] =  $response;
    }      
  }  
  if ($response) {
          return response()->json([
                    'message' => 'success',
                    'data' => $tags,
                    'statusCode' => 200,
                    'status' => 'success'
                ], 200);
  }
```

But now each place you would need to check whether responses are null or not.

## Why private or protected or public?

Check this answer : [What is the difference between public, private, and protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361553/what-is-the-difference-between-public-private-and-protected)

I quote

> - public scope to make that property/method available from anywhere, other classes, and instances of the object.
> - private scope when you want your property/method to be visible in its own class only.
> - protected scope when you want to make your property/method visible in all classes that extend current class including the parent class.

Comment: That would still return the same error, nothing really changed

Comment: Sorry but I didn't got your point @brombeer

Comment: `private $response;` line shows `syntax error, unexpected private`

Comment: @Mege can you show the code just above this line, maybe you are not closing something

Comment: Am closing everything. this whole code is given inside a function in a class. Is that the problem?  like this - `class UserNotificationsController extends Controller
{  public function insert(Request $request)
    {`

Comment: No, it should not be a problem, I have updated the code with $response =  null, try now

Comment: that again shows the same error - `syntax error, unexpected private`

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare a `null` or an empty array in a `$response` variable and you will be able to get the data out of the loop!