# What is the purpose of an abstract?

Tags: php, abstract-class

am wondering when should I use the abstract? I've been digging for a simple code example in google but couldn't find any .. BTW I discovered 'abstract' just an hour ago while am learning **PHP** .. may someone please  post a simple example for me ? thank you

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: Lets say you write 2 separate classes and it seems like you are reusing same logic in both of them as a method, well you can just create an abstract class for that to keep everything more compact and maintainable.

Comment: @Areg so you mean it just reduces the code ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an abstract class in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558559/what-is-an-abstract-class-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Inside abstract class you can use abstract methods. So, you can use it in usual methods. And concrete childs of abstract class have to implement abstract methods.

```
abstract class AbstractDonator
{
    public function donateMinimum(): void
    {
        // this method can be complex
        $minimum = 10;
        $this->donate($minimum)
    }
    abstract protected function donate(int $money);
} 

class ConcreteDonatorOne 
{
    protected function donate(int $money)
    {
        $donateProvider = new PlayPal();
        $donateProvider->pay($money);
    }
}

class ConcreteDonatorTwo 
{
    protected function donate(int $money)
    {
        $donateProvider = new Scribe();
        $donateProvider->transfer($money);
    }
}
$donators = [
    new ConcreteDonatorOne(),
    new ConcreteDonatorTwo(),
];

foreach ($donators as $donator)
{
    $donator->donateMinimum();
}
```